# Is there a difference between geth and the cpp-ethereum CLI?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum, cli

I am a cpp dev and i want to have a look at the ethereum code so i chose the cpp-ethereum repo.

Do geth and cpp-ethereum have the same CLI commands? I wasn`t able to find a list of the commands for cpp-ethereum (I can look at the argv loop but I also need the command list for quick reference).

Comment: One difference I have already noticed is that you have different commands for the JSON RPC, i.e. geth --rpc vs eth -j. Is there a reason the CLIs are not uniform across clients? And are there differences between the other clients as well, e.g. parity, python ethereum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have extensively used Geth and Geth-CLI. As far as I know, the only way we can interact with ethereum-cpp is using one of the methods [mentioned in the documentation](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/connecting-to-clients/index.html#connecting-to-clients).

I didn't even expect geth and ethereum-cpp to have same/similar commands. Geth has a CLI based off the golang debugger. Although, all types of ethereum node can be interacted using the [web3 libraries](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/connecting-to-clients/index.html#connecting-to-clients).